# Understanding the python print output with two variables

Tags: python-3.x, printing

```
>>> a=10
>>> print(str(a)[a==10])
0
>>> print(str(a)[a=='10'])
1
>>> print(str(a)[a=='11'])
1
```

How is the above result of 0 and 1 obtained?

Comment: `False` is derived from `int` type with value 0 and `True` as 1 in Python, so using `a == 10` which translates to the integer 1 (boolean `True`) is returning the number 0 which is the index 1 of `str(10)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's put the `print` statement aside for a second.

1. Inside the square brackets, the expression being evaluated results in a boolean.

   - `a==10` is `True` because `a` is an `int` equal to 10 and `a=='10'` is `False` because `a` is not a `str` with value `'10'`.
2. Each of those booleans is *implicitly* converted to an int because the square brackets are indexing the string. So, `True` becomes index 1 and `False` becomes index 0.
3. The string is indexed. `'1'` is at index 0 of `'10'`, and `'0'` at index 1. *Notice that what is returned is a string* and not an integer, and this is because the result of the whole expression, e.g. `str(a)[a==10]`, is a string in all your examples.

All of this is happening without `print()` being considered. `print()` just prints the representation to the screen. `0` the integer and `'0'` the string look the exact same on the screen. Try using `type()` to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 10, a is a integer value 10
```

In print()
10 == 10 is false so it Will print 2nd position of str(a)
which is 0
10 == '10' is true so it Will print 1st position of str(a)
which is 1

Example:

```
a = 12
print(str(a)[4 == 4]) # output 2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because of indexing in strings
let me explain

when you perform `str(a)`, you are typecasting **a** into a string and consequentially the 10 to '10' whereby '10' is a string with 2 characters ('1' and '0')

Now if you have a string with 2 characters, the character in the zeroth index is the first one('1') , while in the first index is the second character('0')

i.e

```
animal = 'cat'
print(animal[0])
>>'c'
print(animal[1])
>>'a'
print(animal[2]) 
>>'t'
```

moving on, now inside the square brackets you have *boolean statements* for which when the value is *True* the output is 1, when the value is *False* the output is 0

therefore `10==10` is true which is `1`,thus `str(a)[a==10]` is `str(a)[1]` which is 0 (the ***1st*** index but ***2nd*** character of '1**0**')

`10=='10'` is `false` which is `0`
thus `str(a)[a=='10']` is `str(a)[0]` which is `1` (the ***0th*** index but ***1st*** character of '**1**0')

`10=='11'` is `false` which is `0`

thus same as 2nd case

`str(a)[a=='11']` is `str(a)[0]` which is `1` (the ***0th*** index but ***1st*** character of '**1**0')